# Delphi 10.2 style change - not all components repaint

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I've been struggling with style changes in an Android app for a few days. I have few TStyleBook components with loaded styles. If in designtime I connect any of these components to form "StyleBook" property and run the program, it's OK. But if in runtime I switch in code: StyleBook: = StyleBook3; it only paint buttons, and the rest of the components are painted with style witch I pinned in designtime.
Everything worked correctly in 10.1 Berlin. After going to Tokyo we started doing so. What could be the reason?

Comment: When I remove all TStyleBook components and load styles from resources, the effect on the screen is the same, but after the application is restarted and the style change it is OK. It looks like the components allow for a one-time change of style after creation ....

Comment: I dynamically change styles in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and don't face such a problem either, but don't have 10.2 to test. Perhaps this is a bug introduced in 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: It must be a Bug in Tokyo. After return with the code to Berlin everything works again.
I am disappointed of Tokyio. I was hoping to fix some issues with Android, especially in the latest patches to 10.2. But after spending many hours over Tokyio I could not force the app to make working. I returned to Berlin.

Comment: This is precisely why our company always stays at least one version behind from the latest and "greatest". Our software is actually still on Seattle because even Berlin has issues.

Comment: @Insane. You are not the only one who is staying with 10.1 rather than using 10.2